# Trouble understanding an SQL query for a many-to-many table

Tags: sql

I have a many-to-many table which manages stock between stores and products
[image]

I'm trying to create a simple query to show all the rows in store_stock but in a more user friendly way by showing the product name and store name.

I've tried a few variations of this but I just keep getting errors

```
SELECT product.product_name, store.store_name, store_stock.quantity
FROM store_stock
INNER JOIN product ON store_stock.product_id = product.product.id
INNER JOIN store ON store_stock.store_id = store.store_id
```

When I do it via phpMyAdmin query tab it runs this: (However I had to change it from LEFT JOINs to INNER JOINs)

```
SELECT `product`.`name` AS `product_name`, `store`.`name` AS `store_name`, `store_stock`.`quantity`
FROM `product`
    INNER JOIN `store_stock` ON `store_stock`.`product_id` = `product`.`product_id`
    INNER JOIN `store` ON `store_stock`.`store_id` = `store`.`store_id`
ORDER BY `product`.`name` ASC, `store`.`name` ASC
```

This works, but what I don't understand is why it runs 'FROM product', instead of 'FROM store_stock' table

Comment: What happens if you rewrite the select statement to pull `store_stock.quantity` first? Assuming there are no missing IDs, the order in which you write the join shouldn't impact the results, but it might impact the execution plan.

Comment: This is because the inner join operator is commutative. Hence you can join the tables in any order. Some DBMS use the specified order as a hint for their execution plan

Comment: Even if there are missing IDs it won't make a difference which order the JOINs are written. The ordering will only be an issue if there are OUTER JOINs.

Comment: Changing the order do not make a difference, the same error(s) show